# How can I right justify one- and two-digit numbers in a centered stack?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to right justify the numbers centered under section with the check boxes and input fields neatly lined up in a column.  This all works until I get to number 10 where 10 and the check box are a little off to the right.

```css
input[type=number], p{
    width:30px;
    margin-left:75px;
    margin-right:75px;
}

#captions h2{
    color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    width:180px;
    border:solid 1px green;
    text-align:center;
}    

#main{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    border:solid 1px black;
}

.inputs{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    width:360px;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}

.inputs span{
    display:flex;
    width:180px;
    justify-content:center;
   
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <span id="captions">
    <h2>Sections</h2><h2># of Questions</h2>
</span>
  <p class="inputs">
    <span>1 &nbsp; <input type='checkbox'></span> <input type="number">
  </p>
  <p class="inputs">
    <span>2 &nbsp;<input type='checkbox'></span><input type="number">
  </p>
  <p class="inputs">
    <span>3 &nbsp;<input type='checkbox'></span><input type="number">
  </p>
  <p class="inputs">
    <span>4 &nbsp;<input type='checkbox'></span><input type="number">
  </p>
  <p class="inputs">
    <span>5 &nbsp;<input type='checkbox'></span><input type="number">
  </p>
  <p class="inputs">
    <span>6 &nbsp;<input type='checkbox'></span><input type="number">
  </p>
  <p class="inputs">
    <span>7 &nbsp;<input type='checkbox'></span><input type="number">
  </p>
  <p class="inputs">
    <span>8 &nbsp;<input type='checkbox'></span><input type="number">
  </p>
  <p class="inputs">
    <span>9 &nbsp;<input type='checkbox'></span><input type="number">
  </p>
  <p class="inputs">
    <span>10 &nbsp;<input type='checkbox'></span><input type="number">
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox is one-dimensional. You'll need to either switch to grid or specify element width to align content across flex containers. Also, don't use whitespace characters for layout. Use flex properties, margin, etc.

One fairly simple approach is to size and center the spans inside the flex elements. You'll have to pick a size which gets you fairly close to whatever *maximum* size you expect to need, then right-align its content. I've added wrappers to get the columns to be 50% width.

```css
input[type=number],
p {
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-right: 75px;
}

#captions h2 {
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  border: solid 1px green;
  text-align: center;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.inputs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 360px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.inputs span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.inputs span span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <span id="captions">
    <h2>Sections</h2><h2># of Questions</h2>
  </span>

  <p class="inputs">
    <span><span>1 <input type='checkbox'></span></span>
    <span><input type="number"></span>
  </p>

  <p class="inputs">
    <span><span>10 <input type='checkbox'></span></span>
    <span><input type="number"></span>
  </p>

  <p class="inputs">
    <span><span>100 <input type='checkbox'></span></span>
    <span><input type="number"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

My friend, it is better to not use static numbers, instead you can use `counter-reset` in CSS or use the `ol` tag to make the numbers dynamic.

Also, by using `ol` tag, you don't need to take care of the style with the numbers.

I put `::marker` in the code to show you that, you can even control the style of the markers.

You can change the `list-style-type` to `decimal` to remove the zero before the single numbers.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: blue;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

#captions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#captions p {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.inputs {
  list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 360px;
  gap: 15px 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.inputs li div {
  display: flex;
  width: 220px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.inputs li::marker {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.inputs input[type=number] {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <header id="captions">
    <p>Sections</p>
    <p># of Questions</p>
  </header>
  <ol class="inputs">
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <input type='checkbox' /><input type="number" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</main>
```